# How to pass an object containing array of object as parmters to API

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch

I am having error with posting nested object array as parameter to API which returns Internal Server 500 error.

```
 let data= {
   id:'1',
   customerId:cid,
   list:list
  };
```

where `list` is array of objects

```
list = [{a:1,b:1},{a:2,b:2},{a:3,b:3}];
```

I have tried converting them to url parameters like

```
var cstr = JSON.stringify(list);
var clist = cstr.replace(/\"([^(\")"]+)\":/g,"$1:");
let urlParameters = Object.entries(data).map(e => encodeURIComponent(e[0])+"="+encodeURIComponent(e[1])).join('&');
```

but I'm recieving `Internal Server Error 500` in console.

and my api request code is

```
fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'x-auth-token': token,
      },
      body: urlParameters
      }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
            return response.json();
      }).then((responseJson) => {
          console.log(responseJson);
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });

    };
```

Comment: Really depends on the data format the server is expecting. What’s the value of `urlParameters`?

Comment: id=1&customerId=cid&list=[{a:1,b:1},{a:2,b:2},{a:3,b:3}]];

Comment: also tried converting the array into encodeUriComponent and still getting same error

Comment: Which format does the server expect? The format you showed is not a standard format. I’d assume the server does not understand that and would expect at least JSON.

Comment: yes server is expecting the json format like above object data. but im having trouble converting them to right format.